# Maximally symmetric spacetime metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, curvature

I was reading Weinberg's book on Gravitation. In chapter 13 he introduces the metric (eq. (13.3.4)):

$$g_{\mu\nu}=C_{\mu\nu}+\frac{K}{1-K C_{\rho\sigma}x^{\rho}x^{\sigma}}C_{\mu\lambda}x^{\lambda}C_{\nu\kappa}x^{\kappa}, \tag{13.3.4}$$

where $C_{\mu\nu}$ are constants and $K$ is the curvature. So, for flat space $K=0$. Following that, he mentions that, straightforwardly, one can calculate the components of the Riemann tensor. To do that you need to find first the inverse metric. Do I have to suppose that $C_{\mu\nu}C^{\nu\lambda}=\delta^{\lambda}_{\mu}?$

Is it that easy to guess the inverse metric? If so what is the inverse metric in that case?

Comment: Hint: Try a somewhat similar ansatz (13.3.4) for the inverse metric (rather than trying to use [Cramer's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) directly).

Answer (score 1):

Let's guess an ansatz of the form:
$$
g^{\mu\nu}=C^{\mu\nu} + A x^{\mu}x^{\nu}
$$
where $C^{\mu \nu}$ is the inverse of $C_{\mu \nu}$ (i.e., $C^{\mu \nu} C_{\nu \rho} = \delta^{\mu} {}_\rho$) and $A$ is some unknown function of position.  If this is to be correct, we must have $g^{\mu \nu} g_{\nu \rho} = \delta^\mu {}_\rho$.  Multiplying this ansatz and the ansatz from (13.3.4), you will get an equation of the form
$$
\delta^\mu {}_\rho = \delta^\mu {}_\rho + \left[ \text{something depending on $A$, $K$, $C_{\mu \nu}$, and $x^\rho$}\right] x^\mu C_{\rho \nu} x^\nu
$$
and demanding that the quantity in square brackets vanishes lets you solve for $A$.